# moving box2d bodies in an arc or curved path

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, physics, box2d-iphone

How can I make a b2Body move in a arc-like or curved path? I have heard about cocos2d Bezier curve function (ccBezier) but this is for moving cocos2d sprites. Or can it be modified to move box2d bodies? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that you can modify it to move physical bodies. In case of CCNode subclasses this function uses `setPosition:` method. If you change position of your body every tick with `SetTransform` method of b2Body object, it will ignore all possible collisions.

You can try to set linear velocity to physical body. In this case you need to change(rotate) velosity vector as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So by tweaking linear velocity I can arrive at a curved path or arc. Aren't there any guidelines to make this try and error process faster? And how does the SetTransform work?

Comment: As a suggestion you can try to change linear velocity as tangent to the curve you want this body move by. And, as Box2D is open-source framework, you can see how it works in code ;-)

Comment: If you have a target point on the curve where the body should move to, so you can set the velocity of the body to move to that point. If you set the velocity fast enough it will get there in one time step. On the other hand if you are talking about making the body move freely along the curve like on a rail, that's another thing entirely.

Comment: @iforce2d: yes, I have a target point. The body is not really moving in the arc-like or (Bezier curve like) path that I want. I have simplying been testing with various linear velocities.

Comment: @Morion: I am not sure how to "change linear velocity as tangent to the curve". I would really appreciate and example and accept it as answer.